# Why react rerender another variable?

Tags: reactjs

Code like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {

  const [menuitems, setMenuitems] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Init")
    setMenuitems(["menu1","menu2","menu3"])
  },[])

  const MenuItems = () => {
    const renderMenuItems = () => {
      if (menuitems && menuitems.length){
        console.log("Render")
        return menuitems.map((name) => {
          return (
            <button key={name}>{name}</button>
          )
        })
      }  
     }

    return (
        renderMenuItems()
     )
  }

  const [searchTi, setSearchTic] = useState('')
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {menuitems && <MenuItems/>}
      <p>Value: {searchTi}</p>
      <input value={searchTi} onChange={(e) => setSearchTic(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

When the input tag is used, the variable MenuItems is reloaded. What's wrong in my code? Why is it rerendering and how to prevent this from happening?
As far as I understand, this happens after setting the variable "searchTi" through the function "setSearchTic". This updates the variable "menuitems " and reloads this section of code:

```
{menuitems && <MenuItems/>}
```

Comment: Remove it out of `App`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using `MenuItems` like it was a component, but it's only a render function. should just call it like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {

  const [menuitems, setMenuitems] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Init")
    setMenuitems(["menu1","menu2","menu3"])
  },[])

  const renderMenuItems = () => {
    if (menuitems && menuitems.length){
      console.log("Render")
      return menuitems.map((name) => {
        return (
          <button key={name}>{name}</button>
        )
      })
    }  

    return null;
  }

  const [searchTi, setSearchTic] = useState('')
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderMenuItems()}
      <p>Value: {searchTi}</p>
      <input value={searchTi} onChange={(e) => setSearchTic(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

**Compact example:**

Also, there's no need to check to the `menuitems.length`. Best way to render the menu items would be something like this:

```
const renderMenuItems = () => menuitems?.map((name) => <button key={name}>{name}</button>);
```

**useMemo:**

If you want to avoid re-render the menu items over and over, you should also use `React.useMemo` like this:

```
const renderMenuItems = useMemo(() => menuitems?.map((name) => <button key={name}>{name}</button>), [menuitems]);
```

Note that it's now an object (similar to your JSX), and you should not call it, just put it as part of your JSX like this:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderMenuItems}
      <p>Value: {searchTi}</p>
      <input value={searchTi} onChange={(e) => setSearchTic(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Yeap, in my example MenuItems is the function but in project this render not only buttons in map. I cut everything out of the code that I thought was unnecessary. Apparently, this moment is key.

Comment: I use menuitems.length cause i get item from api request and i thought that it nice trick

Comment: Using UseMemo returns a memoized value - oks, But in this code ```const renderMenuItems = () => {
    return menuitems?.map((name) => {
      console.log("Again")
      return (<button key={name}>{name}</button>)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderMenuItems()}
      <p>Value: {searchTi}</p>
      <input value={searchTi} onChange={(e) => setSearchTic(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
  );``` console.log is still running and only what is needed is rendered - Why?

Comment: sorry, I'm having hard time understand your question... maybe create a new stack-overflow question? maybe refer me to an example?

Comment: I create project here codesandbox.io/s/react-component-8ixwk for desribe whats happen.I rewrote my code and made it better, now the menu is not rendered, but the console.log function is still executed, why?

Comment: If the `console.log` is executed, the React function component is rendered (virtually). to avoid this, you can use `useMemo` as I mentioned above.
You can see an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-component-forked-hk4em

Comment: I already use useMemo in my code, but I thought that memorization (useMemo) in this case is unnecessary and is a crutch

Comment: why are you use ReactDOM for render element - its better?

Comment: if you want to see your React components on the DOM, you have to render it using ReactDOM...

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question and it seemed interesting so I researched about it and finally, I found out that **NEVER CREATE A COMPONENT INSIDE ANOTHER FUNCTION COMPONENT**.

And I found an article written by Kuldeep Bora.

you can go through the article to understand this completely.

https://dev.to/borasvm/react-create-component-inside-a-component-456b

**React components automatically re-render whenever there is a change in their state or props.**

Function `renderMenuItems` will re-create on every re-render and it is not an issue.
But if you don't want this behavior you can use the `useCallback` hook, and then the function will re-create only when one of the dependencies will change.

useCallback hook docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {

  const [menuitems, setMenuitems] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Init")
    setMenuitems(["menu1","menu2","menu3"])
  },[])


    // this function will re-create for every re-render
    const renderMenuItems = () => {
      if (menuitems && menuitems.length){
        return menuitems.map((name) => {
          return (
            <button key={name}>{name}</button>
          )
        })
      } 
      }
   


  const [searchTi, setSearchTic] = useState('')
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderMenuItems()}
      <p>Value: {searchTi}</p>
      <input value={searchTi} onChange={(e) => setSearchTic(e.target.value)}/>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

Comment: I am just getting started with react and haven’t found the best way for myself to use components yet. The one I used was the easiest one for me. I render not only buttons in a loop, but something else, so I used the component